# console output for tomcat 8 server on linux

Tags: linux, stdout, tomcat8

I have been trying all day, searching on stackoverflow, serverfault, etc, but I can't find out how I can access the console output (stdout, stderr) from my tomcat 8 server

I have checked, but there is no catalina.out, stdout.log or stderr.log file in $CATALINA_HOME/logs

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `cd /` then `sudo find . -name "*.log" | grep tomcat` or `...grep catalina` I'm sure this won't be quick but if all else fails :) not totally sure it'll work for you either i dont have tomcat installed but cant hurt to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Deryck's technique, I found out that the log file was stored in `/var/log/upstart/tomcat.log`

Even though after the fact it seems like a reasonable place to find that file, I know that given my lack of experience I would have never found it without using find on the whole filesystem. Thanks Deryck, you're a live saver!

Answer (score 0):

Look for the process ID of the `java` process running Tomcat, then look into `/proc/<pid>/fd` - there should be symbolic links to files and sockets open by that process. Specifically, look for symbolic links named 1 and 2, these two represent *stdout* and *stderr*.

```
$ pgrep -fl java | grep -i tomcat
```

Comment: I did find the symbolic links, but they did  not contain the expected text